# Google Maps - Batch Geocoding by Postal Code

Tags: javascript, geocoding

I have a list of canadian postal codes that I want tobe able to map on google maps. SO far I have only found this site :

http://batchgeo.com/ | My Attempt and what I want - http://batchgeo.com/map/3b634fc7cbf942db14284c925ff8631b

How can I achieve the same on my own? Can someone share a script?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do the circles like batchgeo- I've never seen that with google maps before. But you can certainly map out multiple places and drop pins on each place.

Check out google's [Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html), it has a lot in there to help you get started, and is all javascript.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the google maps v3 api for [reverse geocoding](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests). This should give you the needed information to place markers on the map